# Últimos 5 registros por semana en base de datos por orden de menor a mayor. BD

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, mysqldb

Tengo intención de sacar los últimos 5 registros por semana en base de datos por orden de menor a mayor.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM document_treballador_pieles_semanal 
    ORDER BY tr_piel_id DESC) c 
WHERE tr_id_treballador=10 AND mes=02 ORDER BY tr_piel_id ASC
```

Cada mes puede tener varias filas pero quiero las ultimas 5 insertadas en base de datos por semana
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que logro entender de tu imagen solo necesitas ese set de datos, los últimos 5 registros de esa semana y en base a ello, solo bastaría con usar **LIMIT** en la consulta:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        *
    FROM
        document_treballador_pieles_semanal
    WHERE
        mes_semana_anio = 8
    ORDER BY
        tr_piel_id DESC
    limit 5) c
WHERE
    tr_id_treballador = 10
    AND mes = 02
ORDER BY
    tr_piel_id ASC
```

La subconsulta debe ir necesariamente con **ORDER BY ....DESC** de lo contrario traería los primeros 5 registros.